# Road with traffic on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, traffic

I have a question about the MKMapView component. I saw that on the native "Map" iOS app, we can draw the roads between different points and we can display the traffic for those roads. Well, that's exactly what I want to do for my app :)

So, I have two questions :

1) Firstly, how can I draw roads on a map. I read a lot of things about MKOverlay, about some samples which do that with JavaScript in UIWebView but what's the best way to do this ?

2) How can I know the traffic on a particularly road ? In order to draw the road in green, orange or red.

Thanks a lot !

Regards,
Sébastien ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately by now `CLGeocoder` class from *iOS 5* is just supporting to process address to geolocation transformation and reverse. It means to find address around the geocode you have or to find geocode of the address you provide. There are no possibilities access road graph to create routes (to select and draw roads precisely) and moreover to control traffic on the exact place. The only things you can do with standard tools is to draw overlays on the `MKMapView` with your own data.

To achieve the results you want I would offer to use the third party resources, *Google Maps API* for example, and use `UIWebView` to present a customized map. [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 TrafficLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TrafficLayer)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @voromax. Unfortunately, the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 TrafficLayer does not support the display of the traffic in France.. Is there other ideas ?

Comment: @SébastienPolytech' that was not asked in the question I was trying to answer. 'What free/paid traffic services do you know which cover France and offer developer's API' could be your next great question.